# Modx formit + fromz duplicate email

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates, modx-chunks, formit

I use the last modx revo with formZ and it duplicates emails. Each time I submit the form I receive the email twice. I can't figure it out. Here is my form tpl:

```
[[!FormIt?
    &hooks=`[[+action]][[+hooks:notempty=`,[[+hooks]]`]]`
    &excludeFields=`submit[[+id]]`
    &submitVar=`submit[[+id]]`
    &formid=`[[+id]]` [[- "Form ID"]]
    &store=`0`
    &storeTime=`900`
    &successMessage=`<p>[[+success_message]]</p>`
    &emailTo=`[[+email:default=``]]`
    [[+properties]]
    [[+validation:notempty=`&validate=`[[+validation]]``]]
    [[+validationText:notempty=`[[+validationText]]`]]
]]

[[!+fi.successMessage]]
[[!+fi.validation_error_message]]

<form class="form [[+identifier]]" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        [[+fields]] 
    </fieldset>

    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" name="submit[[+id]]" value="[[+action_button:default=`Envoyer`]]" class="btn primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

How to avoid duplicating emails? Any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same error. Did you figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use multiple forms on the same page? Or maybe you use conditional calls? Something like:
`[[*someTV:is='12':then='[[!fomz]]':else='']]`

(Note that the `''` should be ``! Just can't use them here.) If so, have a gander at [this.](https://github.com/silentworks/formz/issues/47)

It helped me, although I used `[[If]]` and made only one call. Basically I used the `[[*formzTV]]` call as it is and voilà. One mail, just as it should be.

Comment: Please try to clean up your answers a little bit. You don't need the "lol" and "hope this helps" comments. If you're unsure whether your answer is applicable, you should ask clarifying questions as comments *before answering* to keep your answers concise.